# nodejs request library, get the response time

Tags: node.js

Using the nodejs `request` library: https://github.com/mikeal/request

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://example.com', function (error, response, body) {
   ...
})
```

Is it possible to get the response time on the callback?
The doc mentions response.statusCode. looking at the library source code I also see undocumented response.headers and response.href, but I don't see responseTime or similar.

or, is there an alternative library to `request` that provides the response time?

ps: I know I could do something like this, but that's not a solution, as I am making many async requests and I cannot control when each request will be started.

```
var request = require('request');
var start = new Date();
request('http://example.com', function (error, response, body) {
   ...
   var responseTime = new Date() - start;
})
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The request library can do timing for you ([docs](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback)):

```
request.get({
  url : 'http://example.com',
  time : true
},function(err, response){
  console.log('Request time in ms', response.elapsedTime);
});
```

As the question implies, you could get issues with the approach of starting a timer, calling `request` then stopping the timer in the callback:

```
var start = new Date();
request.get('http://example.com', function(err, response){
  // NOT GOOD
  console.log('Request time plus 5 seconds', new Date() - start);
});
require('sleep').sleep(5); // time-consuming synchronous action
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like

```
var timedReq = function(url, next) {
  var start = new Date();
  request(url, function(err, res, body) {
    res.responseTime = new Date() - start;
    next(err, res, body);
  });
};
```

will do it for you.  This seems small enough that it's probably easier than finding a new library.

Comment: I would recommend using http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime instead of Date. I use it for http://arrowbreaker.com/demos/sup and it gives pretty accurate results.

Comment: @Pickels Hadn't heard of that.  I don't want to introduce the complications of dealing with that `[seconds, ns]` array to my example, but that does seem like a good idea.

Comment: Not complicated at all! `var start = process.hrtime();` and `res.responseTime = parseInt(process.hrtime(start)[1] / 10000000, 10);` Okay, I lied.

Comment: @Pickels I missed the argument version of `hrtime`.  That's pretty handy.  Still, don't you need to sum the seconds and nanoseconds to get the right answer?

Comment: `let diff=process.hrtime(start); res._time=diff[0]+diff[1]/1e9;`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using Date() you could also use process.hrtime. I have a library specifically for these kind of cases that uses hrtime. The library name is [exectimer](https://github.com/alexandrusavin/exectimer).

You could use it like this:

```
var timedReq = function(url, next) {
  var tick = new t.Tick("responseTime");
  tick.start();
  request(url, function(err, res, body) {
    tick.stop();
    next(err, res, body);
  });
};

// when ready check the results with this:
var responseTime = t.timers.responseTime;
console.log(responseTime.min()); // minimal response time
console.log(responseTime.max()); // minimal response time
console.log(responseTime.mean()); // mean response time
console.log(responseTime.median()); // median response time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap any code block with high resolution timers like so:

```
const start = process.hrtime.bigint();
console.log(`do some work...`);
console.log(
  `took ${Number(process.hrtime.bigint() - start) / 1e6}ms`
);
```

This doesn't require any third party libraries and will give you very precise measurements.