# Node JS Request Library elapsedTime value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Node and am having some difficulties with getting the Request library to return an accurate response time.

I have read the thread at [nodejs request library, get the response time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106825/nodejs-request-library-get-the-response-time?newreg=32e7e69def944b1ba413863c6b1ff9ac) and can see that the request library should be able to return an "elapsed time" for the request.

I am using it in the following way :

```
request.get({
  url : 'http://example.com',
  time : true
},function(err, response){
  console.log('Request time in ms', response.elapsedTime);
});
```

The response.elapsedTime result is in the region of 500-800ms, however I can see the request is actually taking closer to 5000ms.

I am testing this against an uncached nginx page which takes roughly 5 seconds to render the page when profiling via a browser (Chrome).

Here is an example of the timing within Chrome (although the server is under load hence the 10s)

[Chrome Profiling example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YhAz.png)

It looks to me like this isn't actually timing the full start to finish of the request but it "timing" something else. It might be the time taken to download the page once the server starts streaming it.

If this is the case, how can I get the actual start to finish time that this request has taken ? The time I need is from making the request to receiving the entire body and headers.

I am running the request like this with `listofURLs` being an array of urls to request:

```
for (var i = 0; i < listofURLs.length; i++) {
    collectSingleURL(listofURLs[i].url.toString(),
        function (rData) {
            console.log(rData['url']+" - "+rData['responseTime']);
    });
}

function collectSingleURL(urlToCall, cb) {
    var https = require('https');
    var http = require('http');
    https.globalAgent.maxSockets = 5;
    http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 5;
    var request = require('request');
    var start = Date.now();

// Make the request
request.get({
    "url": urlToCall,
    "time": true,
    headers: {"Connection": "keep-alive"}
}, function (error, response, body) {
    //Check for error
    if (error) {
        var result = {
            "errorDetected": "Yes",
            "errorMsg": error,
            "url": urlToCall,
            "timeDate": response.headers['date']
        };
        //callback(error);
        console.log('Error in collectSingleURL:', error);
    }
    // All Good - pass the relevant data back to the callback

    var result = {
        "url": urlToCall,
        "timeDate": response.headers['date'],
        "responseCode": response.statusCode,
        "responseMessage": response.statusMessage,
        "cacheStatus": response.headers['x-magento-cache-debug'],
        "fullHeaders": response.headers,
        "bodyHTML": body,
        "responseTime" : Date.now() - start
    };
    cb(result);
    //console.log (cb);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a key point - it take 5 seconds to render, not to just download the page.

The `request` module of node is not a full browser, it's a simple HTTP request, so when you for example request `www.stackoverflow.com`, it will only load the basic HTML returned by the page, it will not load the JS files, CSS file, images etc.

The browser on the otherhand, will load all of that after the basic HTML of the page is loaded (some parts will load before the page has finished loading, together with the page).

Take a look on the network profiling below of stackoverflow - the render finishes at ~1.6 seconds, but the basic HTML page (the upper bar) has finished loading around 0.5 second. So if you use `request` to fetch a web page, it actually only loading the HTML, meaning - "the upper bar".

[image]

Comment: The timing element here isn't the rendering in this instance. The reason I picked the `request` module was because it can grab just the basic HTML so simply.

If you look at the same profile but go to Network and then click on stackoverflow.html and then go to the timing tab, you'll see the results I'd be expecting. 

In my instance, I know the server takes about 5s to serve just the single html file. And that's what I'm trying to time.

Comment: Maybe try to print out the HTML result from the `request` module, and see if you get the same HTML as in Chrome

Comment: The `body` I'm getting from the `request` module is perfect. Everything looks to be great, it's just the timing element I know is wrong. If I use the `request.elapsedTime` it looks to be timing only the download element of the request and not the whole thing, TTFB, DNS Lookup etc. If I time it seperately as in @idbehold example, it seems to give a sequential response, not the specific timing for the one call.

Answer (score 0):

Just time it yourself:

```
var start = Date.now()
request.get({
  url : 'http://example.com'
}, function (err, response) {
  console.log('Request time in ms', Date.now() - start);
});
```

Comment: I've tried that too. That's why I'm wondering if there is something strange about the `request` module or if it's my understanding of async requests in Node. 

If I do as you've suggested I see "Request time in ms 795" but the run time was 5-6 seconds before the console message appeared.

Comment: @Biomaj are you running any code aside from this request?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the specific code I'm running. I'm now certain that it's my understanding of Async requests that is the problem here. If I run it with your timing suggestion in I get :
    url - 5764
    url - 5973
    url - 6056
This appears to just be timing each request from the initial one and not each one specifically on its own. Because it's async, is `start` getting set with when the requests get put in the queue, i.e. almost straight away ?